# Nyro modal peculiar error

Tags: javascript, jquery, nyromodal

I am using [nyromodal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) . When i try to open , the modal using the code below :

```
<a id = "idDef" href="#" onclick="callNyroModal();" >What's idDef ?</a>

function callNyroModal()
{
    alert("Inside Nyro function");
    jQuery("#idDef").nm();
}
```

I see the alert coming up, when i click this link. But then i get this error in firebug :

`TypeError: this.on is not a function`  and the modal does not come up. I am also using jquery(1.4.2/jquery.min.js) here .

Can some one tell me , how can i get rid of this error and let the modal window come up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this:

1. Figure out what line is causing error
2. Set a breakpoint in firebug in that line, run code again.
3. Once execution line is on breakpoint, figure out what "this" is bound to in that context and why it is not jQuery object (I am assuming it should be because this.on is being called). Something must be bind'ing "this" incorrectly. Look for things like bind(), apply(), etc.

Hope that helps.